# All Pages in Google Analytics GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there a GA4 analog to Google Analytics the UA
"Behavior -> Site Content -> All Pages"
feature? Thank you.

Comment: since I did not work with UA, so please explain what you wanna do in GA4? Do you need a tag to get triggered for All Pages?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness. I want to check the pageview history of individual pages on my website. For some pages, if a it doesn't have enough views over the last year, I want to delete it. I know how to do that in UA but not in GA4. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A similar report in GA4 would be the Events report filtered to the page_view event. This can be accessed by navigating to Reports > Engagement > Events then clicking on the page_view event. The User Engagement summary card will display the page title, % of total page views and avg time metrics. The user interface for the built-in reports are setup as referred to as summary cards.

Alternatively, you can create an exploration report in the Explore tab that includes the following dimensions and metrics.

Dimensions

- Page title
- Page path
- Page location

Metrics

- Views
- Users
- Sessions

Comment: This was the information I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fist off, you need to create a `Data Stream` in [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/). you need the `measurement Id` of your created stream. plus, the gtag.js code which should be copied and pasted immediately after the  tag in your website. you can follow [this link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9304153?hl=en) for instructions.

In addition, create an Account and Container in GTM. Follow this link
[Install Google Tag Manager](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6103696?hl=en) to install GTM on your webpage.
Next, a GA4 configuration tag should be created which have to be triggered for all pages:
In [Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) Open “Tags” tab => “New” => click on “Tag Configuration” => select “Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration”.

[image]
Adding [tag assistant plugin](https://tagassistant.google.com/), you can test your changes using`preview` button on top right of your GTM container. If you are satisfied with the result submit and publish  the changes.

Comment: I had done this much, but thank you.